# how to create two flutter flow columns in ListView?

Tags: flutter

I am loading data dynamically from firebase. But, the bottom line is that I should have two columns, but I only have one and I don't know how to fix it.

Can you tell me exactly how I can make two columns? Preferably an example from flutterflow itself

PS: I'm new to flutterflow so I can't figure out how to implement this

```
 List<CategoryCollectionRecord>
                                  listViewCategoryCollectionRecordList =
                                  snapshot.data!;
                              return ListView.builder(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                itemCount:
                                    listViewCategoryCollectionRecordList.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, listViewIndex) {
                                  final listViewCategoryCollectionRecord =
                                      listViewCategoryCollectionRecordList[
                                          listViewIndex];
                                  return Align(
                                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0),
                                    child: Wrap(
                                      spacing: 0,
                                      runSpacing: 0,
                                      alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          WrapCrossAlignment.start,
                                      direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                      runAlignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                                      verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
                                      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding:
                                              EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                                  0, 16, 0, 0),
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: 160,
                                            height: 248,
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color:
                                                  FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                      .secondaryBackground,
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(18.6),
                                            ),
                                            child: Column(
                                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                              children: [
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                      .fromSTEB(13, 16.3, 14.29,
                                                          7.82),
                                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            9.3),
                                                    child: Image.network(
                                                      listViewCategoryCollectionRecord
                                                          .image!,
                                                      width: 132,
                                                      height: 116,
                                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                      .fromSTEB(
                                                          0, 7.82, 0, 8.18),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    listViewCategoryCollectionRecord
                                                        .header!,
                                                    style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(
                                                            context)
                                                        .bodyText1
                                                        .override(
                                                          fontFamily: 'Manrope',
                                                          color:
                                                              Color(0xFF343235),
                                                          fontSize: 12,
                                                          letterSpacing: 1,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.bold,
                                                        ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                Row(
                                                  mainAxisSize:
                                                      MainAxisSize.max,
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                                      CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Padding(
                                                      padding:
                                                          EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                              .fromSTEB(
                                                                  0, 0, 0, 12),
                                                      child: Image.network(
                                                        listViewCategoryCollectionRecord
                                                            .icon!,
                                                        width: 12,
                                                        height: 8,
                                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    Padding(
                                                      padding:
                                                          EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                              .fromSTEB(0, 0, 0,
                                                                  11.72),
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        listViewCategoryCollectionRecord
                                                            .textIcon!,
                                                        style:
                                                            FlutterFlowTheme.of(
                                                                    context)
                                                                .bodyText1
                                                                .override(
                                                                  fontFamily:
                                                                      'Poppins',
                                                                  color: Color(
                                                                      0xFF343235),
                                                                  fontSize: 11,
                                                                  fontWeight:
                                                                      FontWeight
                                                                          .w500,
                                                                ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                                Align(
                                                  alignment:
                                                      AlignmentDirectional(
                                                          0, 0),
                                                  child: Padding(
                                                    padding:
                                                        EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                            .fromSTEB(8.6, 3.7,
                                                                8.6, 0),
```

full Code - [code](https://dpaste.org/5ChLm)

Here is my result and widgets -

[image: Widgets]
[image: result]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you;ve tried so far?

Comment: This is a constructor. No code yet :)

Comment: Please add code for more information.

Comment: Consider using a gridview if that's what you want

Comment: @Ariel ready. Add code

Comment: @Daniil use a GridView.builder() instead of a ListView.builder() for the columns

Answer (score 0):

Use Wrap property.(Share some code for better understanding)

Comment: This is a constructor. No code yet :)

Comment: No constructor outputs all the widgets....share the build method.